# Is there a way to change the default DB scheme where Yii2 migrations are applied?

Tags: postgresql, yii2, frameworks, migration, rbac

I'm using Yii2 framework and to be more specific I need to use migrations to implement the RBAC in my web-app.

I know that exists the following command to automatically generate 4 tables that DbManager uses to store its data:

**yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations**

But the problem is that those tables are generated in the "public" scheme. I need those tables to be generated in another scheme like "appscheme".

**Do I need to generate my own version of these migrations or is there a way to change the default scheme using that command?**

(I'm using Postgresql if that is important)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell the migration command which DB Connection component it should use with `--db` parameter. To do that you must have configured connection for the other scheme in your app configs. Let's assume your configs looks like this:

```php
[
    // default scheme
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=public',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
    //other scheme
    'db2' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=appscheme',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
    // ... other configurations
];
```

By default the migration would use `db` component. But we want it to use the `db2` component. so we need to run the migration like this:

```
yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations --db=db2
```

Be careful, `yii` command uses the console configs so make sure you have both connection components defined in your web and in your console config too.